# JSONArray object have getString(""); not found

Tags: java, json

Imported header files are:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

The line  `String name= jsonarray.getString("name");`

causes the error: `getString("")` is not found

Comment: can you provide the json string you try to parse?

Comment: shouldn't you use an array index to access objects in your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `JSONArray` doesn't have a `getString()` method. For that matter, even a `JSONObject` doesn't have a `getString()` method.

We can only guess without knowing what your jsonArray contains, but my guess is you need,

```
String name= (String) ((JSONObject) jsonarray.get(0)).get("name");
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, I think your `jsonarray` is of type `JSONObject` (not very sure though), in that case use,

```
String name = (String) jsonarray.get("name");
```

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad, did you use the exact string from the answer? Because it doesn't throw up any error for me. If it still gives error, can you put the exact error message??? And I hopy your `jsonarray` is of type `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `org.json.simple.JSONArray` API and there is no such method as `getString(String str)` or `getString("")`

Check `org.json.JSONArray` API for `getString(int index)`.

Comment: Object jsonData = parser.parse(string);           this code need import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException; thts why i use org.json.simple.JSONArray. if i use org.json.JSONArray which method is used for that code

Comment: I hope you will find couple of helpful methods on org.json.* package; like org.json.JSONArray etc.